# How to generate inline plot result for ob-clojure?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, clojure, inline-image, babel

Question: How to generate inline plot image result in Org-mode babel clojure src block?

I tried some ways:

First way: use `:results file :file "clojure-babel-figure-result.png"`

```
#+BEGIN_SRC clojure :session :results file :file "clojure-babel-figure-result.png" :dir "data/images"
(use '(incanter core stats datasets charts io pdf))

(def my-plot (histogram (sample-normal 1000)))

(save my-plot "clojure-babel-figure-result.png")
;; (view my-plot)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
[[file:/home/stardiviner/Org/Wiki/Computer Technology/Programming/Emacs/modes/Org-mode/data/images/clojure-babel-figure-result.png]]
```

The problem is that the generated plot image should be in upper link path. But
it is save to CIDER working directory
`/home/stardiviner/clojure-babel-figure-result.png`.
or Emacs buffer working directory `default-directory` in `/home/stardiviner/Org/Wiki/Emacs/Org-mode`.

Second way: use Clojure code to specify the image path.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC clojure :session :results file :file "clojure-babel-figure-result.png" :var fname="clojure-babel-figure-result.png"
(use '(incanter core stats datasets charts io pdf))
(import 'java.io.FileOutputStream)

(def output-file (FileOutputStream. fname))

(def my-plot (histogram (sample-normal 1000)))

(save my-plot output-file)

(.close output-file)
;; (view my-plot)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
```

I found `ob-clojure.el` does not use `fname` header argument variable when I
inspect variable `output-file`.

Is there a way to let `ob-clojure.el` change working directory?

I have some ideas:

- let ob-clojure.el use babel header argument `:dir` as working directory.

My environment info:

- My Emacs version: `26.0.50`
- My Org-mode version: `9.0.5`

**EDIT**:

The issue is *the generated file save to current working directory*
`default-directory` , not in Org-mode babel block specified ~:dir~ path.

For example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC clojure :session :results file :dir "data/images" :var fname="clojure-babel-figure-result.png"
(use '(incanter core stats charts io))
(def my-plot (function-plot sin -10 10))
(save my-plot "clojure-babel-figure-result.png")
my-plot
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
[[file:/home/stardiviner/Org/Wiki/Computer Technology/Programming/Emacs/modes/Org-mode/data/images/#object[org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart 0x49b53c9e "org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart@49b53c9e"]]]
```

BTW, How to make Org-mode babel generate inline image result with relative path instead of absolute path? Relative path is useful for blog publish etc.

Comment: You may have to output your image to `stdout` instead of a file, or you may have to return the file name?

Comment: Yes, I updated my question, maybe can return a filename. But currently it seems has ob-clojure evaluate issue.

Comment: Don't know if you've solved it, but this answer by @Tobias should help: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/46557/17896

Comment: Looks interesting, but that seems only work in exporting filter. And I solved this problem. Here it is. I will add answer here. https://stardiviner.github.io/Blog/Clojure-Plotting-to-Org-inline-image-in-ob-clojure.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By pass in target directory as path into Clojure code, and use `java.io.File.renameTo` to move generate plot image file to target dir.

Here is the complete story background: https://stardiviner.github.io/Blog/Clojure-Plotting-to-Org-inline-image-in-ob-clojure.html

Here is a complete example:

```
#+begin_src clojure :results file link :dir "data/images" :file "ob-clojure-incanter-move.png" :var dir=(concat (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)) "data/images/")
(use '(incanter core io charts stats))
(import '(java.io File))

(def hist (histogram (sample-normal 1000)))
(save hist "ob-clojure-incanter-move.png")
(.renameTo (File. "ob-clojure-incanter-move.png") (File. (str dir "ob-clojure-incanter-move.png")))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS[<2019-01-22 08:50:16> 60e5c025a7a63284fdd7546af49e6915291a33f5]:
[[file:data/images/ob-clojure-incanter-move.png]]
```