# How to generate the result file for dot source block and include it with another path in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm starting to write blogs with org-mode and org-static-blog,
but now I'm stuck with a problem respecting exporting graphviz dot file to image file.

So I have a code block like this with `(setq org-static-blog-publish-directory "/path/to/blog-site-root/")` :

```
#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file /path/to/blog-site-root/images/2018-12-10-vtable.png :exports results
digraph vtable_example {
    // ...
}
#+END_SRC
```

I want to generate the png while including the image with a relative path `./images/2018-12-10-vtable.png`,
`M-x org-static-blog-publish` generates it but gives me html including the absolute local path, which will be 404 at my blog site.

If I set the header arguments of `:exports` to `none`, then even the image file will not be generated.

So how can I let org export/babel generate the file and then include it with another path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One appropriate place to do such transformations is the collection of export filters.

You could add [`org-export-filter-link-functions`](https://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-export-filter-link-functions) as a [file local](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables) or [directory local](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html#Directory-Variables) variable to set the url export filter for html export. The following file variable setting replaces the string `/path/to/blog-site-root` in `img` urls with `.`:

```
# Local Variables:
# org-export-filter-link-functions: ((lambda (data backend info) (when (string-match "<img src=\"file://\\(/path/to/blog-site-root\\)" data) (replace-match "." nil nil data 1)))))
# End:
```